# Conditional Checkbox to change following field type

Tags: custom-object, custom-button, custom-field, inputcheckboxes, conditional

I have a requirement where by I would like  to have a field type following a checkbox change to a Master-Detail Relationship if the checkbox is check.

E.g
Employee
Visitor         (tick as appropriate)

Name of Injured Person: ________________________________________

If Employee is checked, "Name of injured person" should change to aMaster-Detail look-up field

Is this possible? How do I go about it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a field act as two different types for a single record, so to do exactly what you want isn't possible. What you could do is just use a lookup field (which you presumably have already), and then use validation rules/triggers to prevent changes to the parent value when that box is checked.

If it's for rollup purposes that you want the MD relationship you'll need to do that via code or using an app that can do those calculations.